# ORACLE procedure, variables and handling with data

Tags: oracle

I would need some help, I am trying to build a procedure in ORACLE PL/SQL, that would get the list of unstable indexes from table dba_indexes and this select statement would also build up the statement to fix/alter the index.

So I have SQL statement that generates the alter statements.

```
    SELECT 'alter index '||owner||'.'||index_name||' rebuild online; '
FROM   dba_indexes
WHERE  status = 'N/A';
```

And the output is:

```
alter index OWNER.INDEX_NAME rebuild online;
```

Which is perfect, and this is also the end result then I just have to get the procedure to work correctly and execute alter statements if there is any if not then just finish the procedure.

Now my question would be how can I save data from SELECT statement to 1 variable ? After that I will just check if variable is NULL or not, if null I finish procedure if not null the I would just execute this variable ?

Is that possible and how ?

Many thanks for help.

Comment: just get the count from dba_indexes into a variable in plsql block. If the count is greater then 0 then proceed with building the alter statements dynamically else exit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a variable;  you can use a loop over your query:

```
begin
    for s in (
                    SELECT 'alter index '||owner||'.'||index_name||' rebuild online' as statement
                FROM   dba_indexes
                WHERE  status = 'N/A'
             )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(s.statement);
        execute immediate s.statement;
    end loop;
end;
```

This will simply do the job for every index in your query, or do nothing if the query returns no indexes.